# Expanding Rows in PySpark DataFrame Based on Date Range for Each Week

Tags: python, dataframe, date, pyspark

I'm working with a PySpark DataFrame that looks like this:

| client | family_code | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 1111 | 2019-10-10 | 2019-11-06 |
| 0002 | 1112 | 2020-11-26 | 2021-01-06 |
| 0003 | 1113 | 2020-09-24 | 2020-10-21 |

I want to expand each row into multiple rows, where each new row represents a week within the date range of `start_date` to `end_date`. The first `week_start_date` should align with the `start_date` and the final `week_end_date` should align with the `end_date`. For all other new rows, `week_start_date` and `week_end_date` should represent the start and end of the week respectively.

Here's an example of the desired output:

| client | family_code | week_start_date | week_end_date | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 1111 | 2019-10-10 | 2019-10-13 | 2019-10-10 | 2019-11-06 |
| 0001 | 1111 | 2019-10-14 | 2019-10-20 | 2019-10-10 | 2019-11-06 |
| 0001 | 1111 | 2019-10-21 | 2019-10-27 | 2019-10-10 | 2019-11-06 |
| 0001 | 1111 | 2019-10-28 | 2019-11-03 | 2019-10-10 | 2019-11-06 |
| 0001 | 1111 | 2019-11-04 | 2019-11-06 | 2019-10-10 | 2019-11-06 |
| 0002 | 1112 | 2020-11-26 | 2020-11-29 | 2020-11-26 | 2021-01-06 |
| 0002 | 1112 | 2020-11-30 | 2020-12-06 | 2020-11-26 | 2021-01-06 |
| 0002 | 1112 | 2020-12-07 | 2020-12-13 | 2020-11-26 | 2021-01-06 |
| 0002 | 1112 | 2020-12-14 | 2020-12-20 | 2020-11-26 | 2021-01-06 |
| 0002 | 1112 | 2020-12-21 | 2020-12-27 | 2020-11-26 | 2021-01-06 |
| 0002 | 1112 | 2020-12-28 | 2021-01-03 | 2020-11-26 | 2021-01-06 |
| 0002 | 1112 | 2021-01-04 | 2021-01-06 | 2020-11-26 | 2021-01-06 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

How can I achieve this transformation in PySpark? I'd appreciate any guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check my code. It is not perfect (sorry, i am out of time :D) but it can be a good starting point for you

I was able to generate something similar to your output with few functions:

sequence(start_date, end_date, interval 1 day) - i am using this to generate rows between start_date and end_date

`F.date_trunc(timestamp="date", format="week")` - here i am finding first day of week, to get the last day i am using something similar:

```
F.date_sub(
            F.date_trunc(timestamp=F.date_add(F.col("date"), 7), format="week"), 1
        )
```

Then to align start/end of week to start/end date i am using case/when to cut not fully weeks

When everything is ready i am just grouping it to get desired output

Sample code:

```
import datetime
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

data = [
    ("0001", "1111", datetime.date(2019, 10, 10), datetime.date(2019, 11, 6)),
    ("0002", "1112", datetime.date(2020, 11, 26), datetime.date(2021, 1, 6)),
    ("0003", "1113", datetime.date(2020, 9, 24), datetime.date(2020, 10, 21)),
]

df_1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    data, schema=["client", "family_code", "start_date", "end_date"]
)

windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("client", "family_code").orderBy("date")

dfExplodedAndAlligned = (
    df_1.withColumn(
        "date", F.explode(F.expr("sequence(start_date, end_date, interval 1 day)"))
    )
    .withColumn("start_of_week", F.date_trunc(timestamp="date", format="week"))
    .withColumn(
        "end_of_week",
        F.date_sub(
            F.date_trunc(timestamp=F.date_add(F.col("date"), 7), format="week"), 1
        ),
    )
    .withColumn(
        "start_of_week",
        F.when(
            F.col("start_date") > F.col("start_of_week"), F.col("start_date")
        ).otherwise(F.col("start_of_week")),
    )
    .withColumn(
        "end_of_week",
        F.when(F.col("end_date") < F.col("end_of_week"), F.col("end_date")).otherwise(
            F.col("end_of_week")
        ),
    )
)

#probably agg is not needed here, i wasnt able to run it without any agg, need to figure out somethin better
dfExplodedAndAlligned.groupBy(
    F.col("client"),
    F.col("family_code"),
    F.col("start_date"),
    F.col("end_date"),
    F.col("start_of_week"),
    F.col("end_of_week"),
).agg(F.max("start_date")).orderBy("start_of_week").drop("max(start_date)").show()
```

Output:

```
+------+-----------+----------+----------+-------------------+-----------+
|client|family_code|start_date|  end_date|      start_of_week|end_of_week|
+------+-----------+----------+----------+-------------------+-----------+
|  0001|       1111|2019-10-10|2019-11-06|2019-10-10 00:00:00| 2019-10-13|
|  0001|       1111|2019-10-10|2019-11-06|2019-10-14 00:00:00| 2019-10-20|
|  0001|       1111|2019-10-10|2019-11-06|2019-10-21 00:00:00| 2019-10-27|
|  0001|       1111|2019-10-10|2019-11-06|2019-10-28 00:00:00| 2019-11-03|
|  0001|       1111|2019-10-10|2019-11-06|2019-11-04 00:00:00| 2019-11-06|
|  0003|       1113|2020-09-24|2020-10-21|2020-09-24 00:00:00| 2020-09-27|
|  0003|       1113|2020-09-24|2020-10-21|2020-09-28 00:00:00| 2020-10-04|
|  0003|       1113|2020-09-24|2020-10-21|2020-10-05 00:00:00| 2020-10-11|
|  0003|       1113|2020-09-24|2020-10-21|2020-10-12 00:00:00| 2020-10-18|
|  0003|       1113|2020-09-24|2020-10-21|2020-10-19 00:00:00| 2020-10-21|
|  0002|       1112|2020-11-26|2021-01-06|2020-11-26 00:00:00| 2020-11-29|
|  0002|       1112|2020-11-26|2021-01-06|2020-11-30 00:00:00| 2020-12-06|
|  0002|       1112|2020-11-26|2021-01-06|2020-12-07 00:00:00| 2020-12-13|
|  0002|       1112|2020-11-26|2021-01-06|2020-12-14 00:00:00| 2020-12-20|
|  0002|       1112|2020-11-26|2021-01-06|2020-12-21 00:00:00| 2020-12-27|
|  0002|       1112|2020-11-26|2021-01-06|2020-12-28 00:00:00| 2021-01-03|
|  0002|       1112|2020-11-26|2021-01-06|2021-01-04 00:00:00| 2021-01-06|
+------+-----------+----------+----------+-------------------+-----------+
```